# Strategy for filtering special results based on user permission

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-security

Say I have an application that manages sensitive data such as clients' health records. After much success I attract many clients - some of them whom are famous persons. I now have lots of employees who use this application. However, I want to protect the identity of said "famous" persons by only allowing privileged accounts managers access to "famous" persons' records.

The data for this application is stored in a relation database that has evolved over many years. The 'clients' table has a 'famous' column to indicate records of famous persons; the 'users' table has an 'privileged' column that indicates the employee has access to famous persons' records; assume both are boolean.

I could go pillaging through the entire data layer, adding to where clauses for all queries; I also have to start sending a flag indicating whether the user is "privileged" or not. This is a massive undertaking, but is there another option?

I'm seeking general advice, but my application is written on the Java platform.

Update: I am familiar with Role-based access control and how users, groups, roles, permissions, rights, etc. *could* be laid out in nice normalized fashion, but that is not currently an option. More likely is that I'll refactor and adapt the current system to make use of a framework such as Spring Security.

Comment: Handling user permissions is more a job for the "controller" layer, data layer may be not tre best option to implement security.. How do you manage user authentication/authorization? Add some details.

Comment: If you are in the US I think you will want to be sure you are in HIPPA compliance.  This is no small thing.

Comment: @zerologiko Both authn/authz are home grown. Post login, an authenticated Principle object as well as a UserPermission object is stored in the HttpSession for interrogation by most controllers (yep, this is a web app).

Comment: @AllInOne Yes. And in CA - SB 1386

Answer (score 2):

The general case here is that different users need to have access to different clients. In my experience, this is best implemented using roles. Different users can be assigned different roles. Access to the data is mapped to the roles.

In your case, you might have a Manager role, and an employee role. Managers have access to all records. Employees only have access to the less sensitive records. This association can be managed through tables, in the database: say, role, user_role, and client_role. user_role would map users to roles, and client_role would define which roles have access to the client information.

I would be cautious about adding the "famous" column you describe. The danger is that in the future as new business rules arise you'll find yourself needing more columns, and new code in the data layer to implement this logic. When you manage access through roles then you have a general mechanism, that tends to be more extensible, even if it is a little more work in the short term.

Answer (score 0):

General answer to your general question: look into RBAC (role based access control).  In Java, you could have some user class that has assigned roles.  Each role has a collection of specific permissions (could be an enum).  Then before each protected operation, you have to check if the current user has the relevant permission.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right path: security is a cross cutting concern an "aspect" that needs to be centralized somehow.

To concretely answer your question, you should go for a **framework + taglibrary**, the one you mentioned, Spring Security is a perfect choice that will pay for the effort on the long run. You may also want to use ***Aspect Oriented Programming*** (AOP) to centralize some aspects since Spring include AspectJ.

But you **still need to introduce role and permissions concepts**.. See [this](http://slackspace.de/articles/roles-permissions-with-spring-security-3/) good article.